# What is the meaning of this sentence

Tags: sentence-patterns

There are few bigger wastes than the loss to idleness of hours, days and years by people who would rather be working

Answer (score 1):

The sentence structure is:

- There are (few bigger wastes) than (the loss (to idleness)) of (hours, days and years) by (people who would rather be working)[.]

It's an assertion that to make "*people who would rather be working*" lose "*hours, days and years*" to "*idleness*" is particularly wasteful.

Comment: @sumelic Good point. The second part of my answer already addressed this, so I've just adjusted the bracketing in the first.